# how to get the name of an unknown .XLS file into a variable in Python 3.7

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, filenames

I'm using Python 3.7.

I have to download an excel file (.xls) that has a unique filename every time I download it into a specific downloads folder location.

Then with Python and Pandas, I then have to open the excel file and read/convert it to a dataframe.

I want to automate the process, but I'm having trouble telling Python to get the full name of the XLS file as a variable, which will then be used by pandas:

```
# add dependencies and set location for downloads folder

import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

download_dir = '/Users/Aaron/Downloads/'

# change working directory to download directory
os.chdir(download_dir)

# get filename of excel file to read into pandas
excel_files = glob.glob('*.xls')
blah = str(excel_files)
blah
```

So then for example, the output for "blah" is:

```
"['63676532355861.xls']"
```

I have also tried just using "blah = print(excel_files)" for the above block, instead of the "str" method, and assigning that to a variable, which still doesn't work.

And then the rest of the process would do the following:

```
# open excel (XLS) file with unknown filename in pandas as a dataframe
data_df = pd.read_excel('WHATEVER.xls', sheet_name=None)
```

And then after I convert it to a data frame, I want to DELETE the excel file.

So far, I have spent a lot of time reading about fnames, io, open, os.path, and other libraries.

I still don't know how to get the name of the unknown .XLS file into a variable, and then later deleting that file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you pickup the one that's latest modified.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I forgot to mention that there is only one excel XLS file in the folder, so it wouldn't matter when it was modified. Thanks.

Comment: @AaronRonay -  `os.listdir()` gives you list of files in your directory. Did you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This code finds an xls file in your specified path reads the xls file and deletes the file.If your directory contains more than 1 xls file,It reads the last one.You can perform whatever operation you want if you find more than one xls files.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
   if filename.endswith(".xls"):
    print(filename)
    #do your operation
    data_df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)
    os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
lst = os.listdir()
matching = [s for s in lst if '.xls' in s]
```

`matching` will have all list of excel files.

As you are having only one excel file, you can save in variable like `file_name = matching[0]`

Comment: you are welcome. Accept the answer, if it solved your problem!